# BeautifulSoup: extracting attribute for various items

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

Let's say we have HTML like this (sorry, I don't know how to copy and paste page info and this is on an intranet):

[image]

And I want to get the highlighted portion for all of the questions (this is like a Stack Overflow page). **EDIT**: to be clearer, what I am interested in is getting a list that has:

```
['question-summary-39968',
 'question-summary-40219',
 'question-summary-42899',
 'question-summary-34348',
 'question-summary-32497',
 'question-summary-35308',
...]
```

Now I know that a working solution is a list comprehension where I could do:

```
[item["id"] for item in html_df.find_all(class_="question-summary")]
```

But this is not exactly what I want. How can I directly access `question-summary-41823` for the first item?

**Also, what is the difference between `soup.select` and `soup.get`?**

Comment: In its current form it's not clear what you're trying to select. `soup.select()` works perfectly fine with `CSS` selectors. All `.question-summary` with an `id` => `soup.select(".question-summary[id]")`

Comment: How is that list comprehension not exactly what you want? Does the result need to be ordered differently?

Comment: No, the list comprehension gives me a list that will work just fine for my purposes. I'm just trying to better understand BeautifulSoup and how I could access something like `question-summary-41823` directly. Is that not possible?

Comment: Not sure what’s more direct than that? You get the element and get its attribute. `html_df.find(class_="question-summary")["id"]` if you just want the first one.

Comment: Yes but that will give me just the first one. What if I wanted all of them? Do I **HAVE** to do something like my list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would post my answer here if it helps others.

What I am trying to do is access the `id` attribute within the `question-summary` class.

Now you can do something like this and obtain it for only the first item (object?):

```
html_df.find(class_="question-summary")["id"]
```

But you want it for all of them. So you could do this to get the class data:

```
html_df.select('.question-summary')
```

But you **can't** just do

```
html_df.select('.question-summary')["id"]
```

Because you have a list filled with `bs4.elements`. So you need to iterate over the list and select just the piece that you want. You could do a `for` loop but a more elegant way is to just use list comprehension:

```
[item["id"] for item in html_df.find_all(class_="question-summary")]
```

Breaking down what this does, it:

- It first creates a list of all the `question-summary` objects from the soup
- Iterates over each element in the list, which we've named `item`
- Extracts the `id` attribute and adds it to the list

Alternatively you can use `select`:

```
[item["id"] for item in html_df.find_all(class_="question-summary")]
```

I prefer the first version because it's more explicit, but either one results in:

```
['question-summary-43960',
 'question-summary-43953',
 'question-summary-43959',
 'question-summary-43947',
 'question-summary-43952',
 'question-summary-43945',
...]
```